# Head start JavaServer Faces

Tags: java, jsf, javabeans

I have a couple of probably common thoughts on [JavaServer Faces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaServer_Faces) (JSF) which I want to clear up.

- Is it possible to just add a Java Class and Call methods inside it from a JSF (x) Page?

I can't see how this even could be an issue knowing to do when you program Java and develop webapplications. However, I can't seem to find a concrete and straight forward guide on this.

As a side-note I am using [JDeveloper](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDeveloper) from Oracle.

I want to be able to just create a JSF Page as easy as I create a ASP.NET Page and from somewhat a "Code-behind" I want to process input and display outcome.

Please guide me in the right direction so I can navigate this JavaServer Faces jungle!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's not generally possible to call arbitrary methods in backing beans from your JSF pages.

I suggest reading a decent JSF book or tutorial (the ones on the [IBM website](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jsf1/) are a little old but still well worth reading).

In general backing beans work using "actions".

So, you define something like this in your page:

```
<h:commandLink action="#{backingBean.doSomething}" />
```

Then, in your backing bean you have:

```
public String doSomething() {
    // Your logic goes here
    return "navigation-target";
}
```

The String returned from "doSomething" will be a string as defined in your `faces-config.xml` file, known as an "outcome", which will tell JSF which page to navigate to.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Would it be possible to use Conditions inside a JSF-page or you always return "outcomes" or "views" or whatever it is called in JSF? If i have an action called "Login", do i return a new navigation url or just a boolean?

Comment: you can return a new navigation case, or you can return null in which the page is reloaded.