# Java Faces Return Navigation

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I'm brand new to Java and need help understanding why my faces navigation is not occurring when I invoke a method that returns the navigation string. Here's what I have:

**faces-navigation.xml**

```
<navigation-case>
    <from-outcome>displayStudents</from-outcome>
    <to-view-id>/pages/students.jspx</to-view-id>
</navigation-case>
```

**studentAdd.jspx**

```
<ui:define name="body">
    <h:form id="newStudentForm">
    <p:outputLabel for="newFirstName" value="First Name" />
    <p:inputText id="newFirstName" value="#{studentBB.newFirstName}" />

    <p:outputLabel for="newLastName" value="Last Name" />
    <p:inputText id="newLastName" value="#{studentBB.newLastName}" />

    <p:commandButton value="Save" action="#{studentBB.addNewStudent}" ajax="false"></p:commandButton>
    </h:form>
</ui:define>
```

**StudentBB.java**

```
public String addNewStudent() {
    Student student = new Student();
    student.setFirstName(this.newFirstName);
    student.setLastName(this.newLastName);
    DomainFactory.getStudentManagerImpl().saveOrUpdateStudent(student);

    return "displayStudents";
}
```

The data persists fine down to the DB but the string "displayStudents" is not being seen by PrimeFaces and directing the page to students.jspx. What am I missing? I've tried finding anything similar and only came up with this link which says that by returning the string it should navigate to the page indicated:
[Head start JavaServer Faces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1464875/head-start-javaserver-faces)

I'm running Java SE6 with PrimeFaces 4. Thanks for any help!

Comment: JSF will look for faces-config.xml not faces-navigation.xml, unless you define it to be looked at in your other xmls. change your return "displayStudents" to "students" see what happens, FacesServlet auto adds names to your views and renders them with matching names, so Students will have a nav target of the same. I haven't used JSF with .jspx files though and mostly use .xhtml - check in your web.xml that you have FacesServlet mappings setup for your file types aswell.

Comment: Thanks @VeenarM. That pointed me in the right direction! I discovered that my web.xml file was missing the proper config parameters defined to point to the faces-navigation. Once I added that everything started pointing fine. Thanks